# Paypal IPN Nightmare

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having a nightmare trying to get a Paypal IPN listener to work properly. The code I have thus far is as follows (forgive the lengthy code post):

```
require_once('../Connections/dpp.php');
mysql_select_db($database_dpp, $dpp);


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use: 
    $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$business = @$_POST['business'];
$payment_status = @$_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = @$_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = @$_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = @$_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = @$_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = @$_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = @$_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = @$_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = @$_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = @$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = @$_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = @$_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = @$_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = @$_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = @$_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = @$_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = @$_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = @$_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = @$_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = @$_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = @$_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = @$_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = @$_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = @$_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = @$_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = @$_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = @$_POST['item_number'];
$tax = @$_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = @$_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = @$_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = @$_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = @$_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = @$_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = @$_POST['invoice'];
$custom = @$_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = @$_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = @$_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = @$_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id = @$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = @$_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = @$_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = @$_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = @$_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = @$_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = @$_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = @$_POST['reason_code'];


if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // Write transaction record to database
            $fecha = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");

            $nm=0;
            if ($nm == 0){
                if ($txn_type == "cart"){
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        $xml .= "    <$key>$value</$key>".PHP_EOL;
                    }

                    $strQuery = "insert into p_paypal_payment_info(paypal_paymentstatus,paypal_buyer_email,paypal_payer_status,paypal_firstname,paypal_lastname,paypal_street,paypal_city,paypal_state,paypal_zipcode,paypal_country,paypal_mc_gross,paypal_mc_fee,paypal_memo,paypal_paymenttype,paypal_paymentdate,paypal_txnid,paypal_pendingreason,paypal_reasoncode,paypal_tax,paypal_datecreation,paypal_verify_sign,paypal_payer_id, paypal_mc_currency,paypal_post_data) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','" .$payer_status."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."','".$verify_sign."','".$payer_id."','".$mc_currency."','".$req."')";
                $result_payment = mysql_query($strQuery, $dpp) or die(mysql_error());

                // write individual cart items to database
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
                    $z_test_qry = "INSERT INTO z_qry_test(qry_id, qry_text) VALUES (NULL, 'cart_items" . $num_cart_items . "')";
                    $result_test = mysql_query($z_test_qry, $dpp) or die(mysql_error());

                     $itemname = "item_name".$i;
                     $itemnumber = "item_number".$i;
                     $mc_handling = "mc_handling".$i;
                     $mc_gross = "mc_gross_".$i;
                     $quantity = "quantity".$i;
                     //CODE GET TO HERE THEN APPEARS TO STOP EXECUTING



                      $strQueryCart = sprintf("insert into p_paypal_cart_info(cart_txnid,cart_itemnumber,cart_itemname,cart_quantity,cart_mc_handling,cart_mc_gross) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", GetSQLValueString($txn_id, "text"),GetSQLValueString(@$_POST[$itemnumber], "text"),GetSQLValueString(@$_POST[$itemname], "text"), GetSQLValueString(@$_POST[$quantity], "text"), GetSQLValueString(@$_POST[$mc_handling], "text"), GetSQLValueString(@$_POST[$mc_gross], "text"));

                     $result_cart = mysql_query($strQueryCart, $dpp) or die(mysql_error());


                 } // end FOR Loop

                }
            }

            // send mail confirmation to merchant
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation

            $mail_From = "From: me@mybiz.com";
            $mail_To = "buyer@yourbix.com";
            $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
            $mail_Body = $req;

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
            }

            mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $emailtext . "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);

        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

?>

The peculiar thing is if I run this script locally, passing the contents of the POST in the URL and processing as a GET, it works fine. I can only assume there is an issue in the code, but I can't see it and as much as I try to debug the processing (by writing data and variable values to the database as strategic points) I cannot get it to work. It gets to a point about three quarters of the way down and apprears to stop executing (as indocated by the comment in the code above). I know for a fact it doesnt execute the following line, no matter what it is.

This is based on a script grabbed from the paypaltech.com script generator so I kind of hoped it would work pretty easily.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Minor non-obvious bug: `'0' == ''` in PHP, so your code would convert a legitimate zero into a null. You'd want to use the strict comparison operators (`!==` and `===`) for checking against empty strings.

Comment: Good spot, although this won't be causing the issue I am having...

Comment: No. I'd suggest spitting out the text of the query you're building at the spot where things appear to die, as well as some `echo 'got to stage XXX'` type calls so you can see exactly where things are dying.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. As the script is called by PHP and never rendered in the front end, I have been writing stuff out to database at relevant points. I have added in a line to do this directly after the `$strQueryCart =` line and it never gets executed. This is what I can't figure out...

Comment: although a statement to do exactly the same directly before the `$strQueryCart =` line DOES get executed - go figure!

Comment: Anything in the error log? It could either be in a dedicated PHP log file (`error_log` directive in php.ini) or in Apache's own error_log.

Comment: Nothing - error logging was turned off on this particular server, but just enabled it (and yes, restarted apache!), tried again and nothing... really losing the will to live with this one - I have even commented out the `$strQueryCart =` line and replaced with a simple insert of a NULL record into the database, in case one of the variables was wonky, but it still won't execut. I have increased script runtime and POST variable size in php.ini, all to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

To get IPN to work, you need to enable it from within your paypal account. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes - the code works all the way down to the point indicated in the code. Its not a paypal configuration issue.

Comment: jray0039, that's not true. You can initiate IPN by using notify_url (Website Payments Standard) / NOTIFYURL in SetExpressCheckout as well (although this doesn't work if ipn is Disabled on your account.)

Comment: Have a look at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369069/how-do-i-turn-of-ipn-paypal-in-magento-webshop/9371225#9371225 which explains the various states of IPN within PayPal and how you can control this, either via the PayPal Profile or by passing certain parameters in your API call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the code I used from within sandbox environment. The code is in c# but you should be able to get the idea.

```
string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox );

            //Set values for the request back
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
            string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
            strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
            req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
            StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();

            if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {
                var phone = Request.Form["item_number"].ToString();
                var amountPaid = Request.Form["payment_gross"].ToString();

                string credits;
                var temp1 = Request.Form["item_name"].ToString();
                var temp2 = temp1.Split(' ');
                credits = temp2[0].ToString();

                GetPurchaseRequest purchasedetails = new GetPurchaseRequest();
                purchasedetails.AmountPaid = Convert.ToDouble(amountPaid);
                purchasedetails.Credits = Convert.ToInt32(credits);
                purchasedetails.Phone = phone;
                string xmlString = XmlHelper.UploadXmlString<GetPurchaseRequest>(purchasedetails, "Purchase");
            }
            else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
            {
                //log for manual investigation
            }
            else
            {
                //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I don't think it will help. I have now written three separate IPN helper scripts, all of which are being processed by my sandbox account. The only one which doesnt work is the one in my post above. The other two (which just send out emails, don't write to database) work absolutely fine.

Comment: ok. I wish I could help more but its been a while since I have coded in php. I did see that you have quite a bit of code in your snippet. I would start by making it very basic. Get it to work with basic code and build from there until you can find where it breaks. Then you can troubleshoot the real problem. I know this is general help, but this is how I solve 90% of my own problems :)

Comment: Just what i'm doing now. Hate going backwards but don't think I have much choice. Will post on here if I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, re-writing the script from scratch seems to have resolved the issue. The only thing I can think of is that the original version may have been trying to write invalid data types into columns in the database. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I was stuck on a similar issue, and I can see the same bug in the code posted in the question.

Whilst you are posting to "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com" the "Host" part of the header must still read "www.paypal.com".

Odd as their current example doesn't use the "Host" part of the header and the old examples used to use the same "Host" value as the domain used in the request (which is the same as not including the "Host" value in the header).