# How do I turn off PayPal IPN in Magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

When people make a successful payment with PAyPal in my Magento webshop it automatically creates an invoice with unique invoice number. For bookkeeping reasons, I have to disable it.

I've been searching for a few weeks now but I still haven't found the solution for this problem. What I know so far is that this is caused by IPN. The problem is I don't know how to turn this off without damaging my shop or paypal payments.

Some more specs:
- Version: Magento 1.6.2.0
- Standard paypal

Files containing IPN:
www/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers

Answer (score 2):

"Turning it Off" is sort of vague, but there's no configuration setting on the Magento side that will allow you to accept PayPal standard payments using the IPN system but not create invoices.  You're looking at writing custom code to do this.  Here are some starting points.

PayPal IPN works with a callback URL.  That is, once PayPal has processed a payment, it fetches a specific URL from Magento with a specific set of data in the post field.  Then, based on this information, appropriate action is taken (an invoice is created, a credit is issued, etc.).  So the quickest way to achieve your goal would be to change the IPN URL in your PayPal configuration.  This means PayPal is still notifying a URL, but not the Magento URL, and an invoice never gets created.

If that doesn't work or has unacceptable side effects, here's the code points you're interested in. Assuming you're using a standard Magento PayPal setup with an IPN URL configured at

```
http://yourstore.example.com/paypal/ipn/
```

Magento will handles this request with the `indexAction` method in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php
public function indexAction()
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        Mage::getModel('paypal/ipn')->processIpnRequest($data, new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

The business logic for this method (including your invoice creation) starts in the `paypal/ipn` model.  In a standard system this resolves to the class at

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php
class Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn
{
    ....
}
```

Trace the code from here to find the method you'll want to `rewrite` and implement your desired functionality changes (not creating an invoice).  Your best bet will be setting up a PayPal developer sandbox account so you can repeatedly hit the URL until you've traced your code to the right spot.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

instead of hacking your core Magento files, just turn off IPN within PayPal.

By default, there are three states for PayPal IPN:

On
Off
Disabled
The first option will let you specify an IPN URL within your PayPal Profile, and you'll have access to 'IPN History' under the 'History' tab. All IPN data for your account will be sent to the URL you specified, unless you override it with notify_url / NOTFIFYURL on a per-transaction basis.

The second option will turn IPN off on your account, but you can still use it by setting notify_url / NOTIFYURL on a per-transaction basis. This is what Magento uses.

The third option will stop generating IPN messages for your account, even if your shopping cart (Magento, in this case) specifically asks for IPN messages by sending notify_url / NOTIFYURL. No IPN messages will be delivered whatsoever.

To set IPN to 'Disabled', first set it to 'On' in your PayPal account and provde a URL to an IPN address (though this can be any address, just enter http://www.google.com/ for example).
Once enabled, look for the option stating 'Stop receiving IPN messages (Disable)'. Use this to disable IPN altogether.

Source:-https://lastdropofink.co.uk/tools/magento/magento-paypal-ipn/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you should change **Payment Action** to **Authorization** for your paypal payment method. See more info there:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store#1.1

Comment: I have tried this option but as soon as I claim the money it makes an invoice. Paypal gives you 3 days to claim the money and sometimes i have to wait one week before i can make an invoice. Thanks for trying to help out!

Thanks again Alan, Robert and Zyava. I'lle keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

Or, instead of hacking your core Magento files, just turn off IPN within PayPal.

By default, there are three states for PayPal IPN:

1. On
2. Off
3. Disabled

The first option will let you specify an IPN URL within your PayPal Profile, and you'll have access to 'IPN History' under the 'History' tab. All IPN data for your account will be sent to the URL you specified, unless you override it with notify_url / NOTFIFYURL on a per-transaction basis.

The second option will turn IPN off on your account, but you can still use it by setting notify_url / NOTIFYURL on a per-transaction basis. This is what Magento uses.

The third option will stop generating IPN messages for your account, even if your shopping cart (Magento, in this case) specifically asks for IPN messages by sending notify_url / NOTIFYURL. No IPN messages will be delivered whatsoever.

To set IPN to 'Disabled', first set it to 'On' in your PayPal account and provde a URL to an IPN address (though this can be any address, just enter http://www.google.com/ for example).
Once enabled, look for the option stating 'Stop receiving IPN messages (Disable)'. Use this to disable IPN altogether.

Comment: I will try this solution first as it is not so drastic and i will still be able to use IPN for my services who don't make auto invoices. It would be frustrating if that is the case because i already contacted the Paypal webmasters and they said i had to do this within Magento. I'lle keep you posted if it worked. I Just disabled it.

Comment: If you disable it, you will not be able to use IPN at all with that PayPal account. It will disable the entire IPN functionality on an account-level.

Comment: Dear Robert, Thank you for the additional information. I just had an order with paypal and it seems it works. The only downside is that Magento also doesn't send a confirmation e-mail to the customer and me because the status is pending. Do you perhaps know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Since it relies on IPN confirmation for this, there's very little to be done, besides once again modifying Magento core files.

Answer (score 0):

What I’ve been really surprised by over the past few weeks is the number of sites that don’t actually have this turned on and it’s just not limited to self-builds even the really expensive Magento builds are missing this out this as a step.

Turning on the PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN for short) is an excellent idea as means that when a customer pays for an item using PayPal then the payment information will be updated on the Magento order details in the administration panel.

It only takes a few moments to enable and I’ll show you how to enable IPN for your Magento site below. This will mean that when you receive an order via PayPal Express for example, you can actually see the transaction details in Magento and if you’re using eSellerPro and have the eSellerPro Connector enabled for sales order processing, your order & payment details will match up automatically.

Setting this up won’t take more than a few moments and here are 6 simple steps to do this:

## 1 Login to PayPal

## 2 Hover on “Profile” and select “My Selling Preferences”

## 3 Halfway down the page, click on “Update” next to “Instant payment notifications”

Now enter the following details:

Notification URL – This is simply http://your-magento-store.com/paypal/ipn/ replacing “your-magento-store.com” with your website address. <= This is the part that normally trips everyone up as they’re not sure what to enter here.
IPN messages – Set this to “Receive IPN messages (Enabled)”
Press Save

That’s it job done.

To test whether IPN is working or not is dead simple, just make a test transaction through your website (you will need a secondary PayPal account for this) and a few minutes later, check on the order in your Magento admin panel has been updated with the PayPal transaction details.

To help you, I have put to images below, the image on the left has no IPN details, the image on the right does.